# Non-abelian groups of order $50$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Are there non-abelian groups of order $50$? If so, how many elements of order $2$ can they have? Such a group would have a unique $5$-Sylow-group, so it would have at least $25$ elements not of order $2$. But what can happen with the rest – is it possible that it has also $25$ elements of order $2$?

Comment: The direct product of the dihedral group of order 10 with $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ has order 50 and is non abelian.

Comment: @Watson Ah, simple. Nice.

Comment: The dihedral group of order $50$ is also an example which has precisely $25$ elements of order $2$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That’s an answer, not a comment.

Comment: The last non-abelian group is a semidirect product of $C_5\times C_5$ and $C_2$, having $25$ elements of order $2$ and $24$ elements of order $5$. Its center is trivial.